# Grails War unable to deploy to Tomcat - Error: org.postgresql.Driver not found

Tags: java, grails, tomcat7, war, postgresql-9.3

I have a grails application which use PostgreSQL. Everything is ok, when i use grails console as:
 grails run-app
 grails test-app
 grails clean
 grails war
 grails compile

In BuildConfig, I have:

```
dependencies {
    runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1100-jdbc41'
}
```

But when I try to package .war file, copy that file to $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ where Tomcat apps are deployed, and start Tomcat server by: catalina.sh start. And I got error messages in tracktrace.log:

```
21-Mar-2014 14:45:57.701 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: org.postgresql.Driver
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:253)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:181)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:699)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:633)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:484)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:142)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126)
```

I try to list file/folder in /META-INF/lib, and I see:

```
....
postgresql-9.3-1100-jdbc41.jar
....
```

I don't know what the matter with this. Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: if your question is answered, please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Move the JDBC driver JAR to Tomcat's /lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

## Not only the Library and Jar file Make sure you datasource setting is correct as follow:

```
dependencies {
        runtime "postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4"
    }

dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"
    username = "iqbal"
    password = ""
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 3
//    cache.region.factory_class = 'org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory' // Hibernate 4
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/seram"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/seram"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
            properties {
                maxActive = -1
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
                testOnBorrow=true
                testWhileIdle=true
                testOnReturn=false
                validationQuery="SELECT 1"
                jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. It's right! Because it's running when use grails command. But I find out the solution, that I need to cope database driver library to lib folder of web server ex: tomcat. Thanks